# Issue with regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using regex in javascript to check if a string contains a tag called 'tag-name'. See below:

```
    someText
    <other>more text<other>
</tag-name>
```

I want to extract "tag-name", only if it occurs following the first instance of '<' in the string. So in the example above, my regex should not find a match as there is a '<' character at the 'other' tag.

In this example below, it should return 'tag-name' as it occurs after the first occurance of '<'.

```
someText
</tag-name>
<other></other>
```

Can anyone suggest how I can get this to work, so far I have used this expression:

```
<*?tag-name
```

but, it is extracting the tag-name string regardless of where it occurs.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
/^[^<]*<[^<]*tag-name/
```

The logic is to match the start of the string, zero or more non-`<` characters, `<`, zero or more non-`<` characters, then your tag name.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/yL3qY7/2) — Be sure to see the Unit Tests (link on the lower left) to demonstrate both of your cases.